# How do I define a struct property to accept Linear or Angular gradients in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to create a View that can accept a Linear or an angular gradient as a property. Although both gradients conform to ShapeStyle, I can't define the properties type with it.

Here's what the view looks like if it accepts just a LinearGradient:

```swift
struct NewView: View {
  var fill: LinearGradient

  init(fill: LinearGradient = LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.green, Color.blue]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom) {
    self.fill = fill
  }

  var body: some View {
    Circle()
      .stroke(fill, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 25))
  }
}
```

Ideally it will accept either Gradient in the fill property without the need for any other properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the AnyShapeStyle type with two init blocks like this:

```
struct NewView: View {
  var fill: AnyShapeStyle

  init(fill: LinearGradient = LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.green, Color.blue]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom) {
    self.fill = AnyShapeStyle(fill)
  }

init(fill: AngularGradient = AngularGradient(colors: [.green, .blue], center: .center) {
    self.fill = AnyShapeStyle(fill)
  }

  var body: some View {
    Circle()
      .stroke(fill, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 25))
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Set `ShapeStyle` constraint.

```
struct NewView<Style: ShapeStyle>: View {
    var fill: Style
    
    init(fill: Style) {
        self.fill = fill
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .stroke(fill, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 25))
    }
}
```